# how to get the java source code from the compiled code

Tags: java

i have the compiled code of a method in the ear file and i need to get the source code from it.

when i place the same code and produce the ear the change is not performed.

```
public void changeLanguageEvent(ValueChangeEvent event) {
    String language = (event.getNewValue() != null) ? (String)event.getNewValue() : null;
    setLanguage(language);
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    session.setAttribute("locale", language);
}
```

I want to know how I can get the source code from the compiled code.

Comment: you can't compile a method, always minimal a class. "the change is not performed", what is that supposed to mean? Either way, if you want to know how to get source code from a .class file, find a java decompiler

Comment: Open the EAR with a ZIP file editor, open whatever this went into (WAR? JAR?), there's a `class` folder in it, find your class, feed it to a decompiler (just search for it, there's plenty).

Comment: `I want to know how I can get the source code from the compiled code.` - use decompiler

Comment: The class of tools that handles this is called "decompiler". Note they don't produce perfect result since compilation usually is a destructive process (for instance, unless specified otherwise, comments won't be included in the compiled class)

Comment: Alternately, you can use a debugger to step through the code.  Properly configured a debugger will show you the code as it steps through each line.

Comment: hi All ,i attached the code form the decompiler itself, but when i paste this same code and run in my eclipse the change is not reflecting. To describe when i change the language dropdown, the login attachments based on the language should be displayed, but this doesnot happen with the code above from the decompiler

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tool like http://www.javadecompilers.com/ or another similar

Comment: i have taken the code from the decompiler and attached but that doesnt help.